# Trying to pass preprocessor directive via command line in bash script

Tags: c, bash, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to write a bash script that will take in an optional argument,
and based on the value of that argument, compile code using that argument
as a preprocessor directive. This is my file so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

OPTIMIZE="$1"

if[ $OPTIMIZE = "OPTIMIZE" ] then
    echo "Compiling optimized algorithm..."
    gcc -c -std=c99 -O2 code.c -D $OPTIMIZE
else
    echo "Compiling naive algorithm..."
    gcc -c -std=c99 -O2 code.c 
fi
```

However, it doesn't seem to like the "-D" option, complaining that there is a macro name missing after -D. I was under the impression -D defines a new macro (as 1) with name of whatever is specified. I wanted "OPTIMIZE" to be the name of that macro. Any hints?

Comment: Why do you have such a script? What for? How would `code.o` be used? Why not use `make` ?

Comment: This was just a excerpt of the code; other things are done with code.o. However, you're right, a Makefile is probably the only correct method here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-D` should be glued to the name (ie `-DFOO` not `-D FOO`)

```
     gcc -c -std=c99 -Wall "-D$OPTIMIZE" -O2 code.c
```

and you forgot to pass `-Wall` to `gcc`. It is almost always useful.

BTW, you might consider (even for a single file) using `make` with two phony targets: the default one (e.g. `plain`), and an `optimized` one.

Comment: Thank you very much! For some reason the idea of a Makefile never occurred to me...